# Typescript Specific Dictionary Interface

Tags: typescript, types, interface, sequelize.js

I am trying to create an interface for Sequelize models that I can use throughout my App.

I am currently using

```
interface IModel {
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

I am looking for something more specific such as

```
interface IModels {
    [key:'post']:typeof Post,
    [key:'user']:typeof User,
}
```

I remember something with a Discriminating type Unions, but I'm getting something wrong with my nesting.   In addition to the dictionary I am trying to append models with models.sequlize = sequelize

I also am loading this in from a path, so I do not necessarily know the model names at the time they are being loaded

```
export function registerModels(sequelize: Sequelize) {
  const thisFile = path.basename(__filename);
  const modelFiles = fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
  const filteredModelFiles = modelFiles.filter(
    (file) => file !== thisFile && file.slice(-3) === '.js'
  );
  filteredModelFiles.forEach((file) => {
    const f = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
    if (f.default) {
      const model = f.default(sequelize);
      models[model.name] = model;
    }
  });
  Object.keys(models).forEach((modelName) => {
    if (models[modelName].associate) models[modelName].associate(models);
  });
  models.sequelize = sequelize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a record.

type MyType = Record<"post" | "user", typeof Post | typeof User>